# What is LD_LIBRARY_PATH for R in a conda envrionment?

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio-server

I have an a GCP virtual machine running RStudio Server. It has a public IP and I was accessing it at `#.#.#.#:8787`. During an ubuntu (22.04) update the server stopped working via the public IP. `sudo rstudio-server verify installation` showed that libR.so could not be found. However, if I ssh tunnel to the vm I can access RSS at `localhost:8787`.

According to the folks at RStudio, the problem may have to do with setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH for R in the `/etc/rstudio/rserver.conf` file. However, I can't seem to figure out what that should be set to.

I tried `/home/balter/conda/lib/R/lib`, but that did not fix the problem.

There is more detail [in the issue I filed](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12281).

My question here is what to try instead of `rsession-ld-library-path=/home/balter/conda/lib/R/lib` in the `/etc/rstudio/rserver.conf` file?